# What's the best way to stop page scroll within a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu on mobile where the page is scrolling at the top when I open the menu.

What's the best way to solve this? [here is an example](https://4309.co.uk)

Tried:

```html
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">
  <a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
    <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
      document.body.classList.toggle("body-overflow");
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Didn't work.

Added css:

```
.body-overflow {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Didn't work.

What I've realised is that there are two overlapping touchable or scrollable areas. Touching the menu area enables you to move the page behind it. So if there is a way of creating an attribute z-index?

Comment: Share code of menu

Comment: Please see edited question

Answer (score 1):

Your link points to `#`, which is a way of linking to an element on the same page. An empty fragment (`#`) links to the top of the page, causing the browser to scroll. (If you linked to `#some-section`, the browser would scroll to the element with the ID of `some-section`).

So, in your case, you need to change your click handler to:

```
onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">
```

This makes the return value of the event handler return false, which signals to the browser that the default browser behavior (scroll) should not take place.

Your code, modified:

```html
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">
  <a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
    <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <script>
    function myFunction(el) {
      el.classList.toggle("change");
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

The other issue (menu pushing the page content down) can be solved with the following CSS:

```css
#site-navigation {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Yep. I just copied what you wrote exactly and pasted it and still scrolling when menu opened.https://4309.co.uk. Do you you see it? Right at the top.

Comment: On the website you linked to, you're currently calling `myFunction` twice. Once without the `return false;`. You should remove the first one, so you only have: `<div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">`

Comment: Which one do i remove?

Comment: Remove the one that doesn't have `return false;`. There should be only one `onclick` handler. The div should look like this: `<div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">`. Right now it looks like this: `<div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)"onclick="myFunction(this); return false;">`

Comment: What should i remove exactly please? As in please write what i need to remove.

Comment: Remove `onclick="myFunction(this)"`

Comment: onclick="myFunction(this) is only showing once in my header.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214990/discussion-between-nicoqh-and-stacksof99).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways you can solve this. One way would be to make your top bar sticky. Another option would be to make your whole navigation fixed. Something else you could try is to turn off scrolling on the body element when the menu is expanded. Each of these have pros and cons and you might need to play around with them to find which works best for you.

Comment: You mean position:sticky?